# Visualizing projective closures - is it okay to just think of the affine case?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

This question is quite general and has been discussed on MSE before, however my case is a little bit different and I'm wondering about the geometric interpretation of a specific example. I think that this example is primarily what I need to complete my intuition for projective spaces in algebraic geometry.

Consider the affine elliptic curve $Y=Z(y^2-x^3+x)\subseteq\mathbb A^2$. The generator $y^2-x^3+x$ of $I(Y)$ can be homogenized by adding the necessary $w$'s, yielding $wy^2-x^3+w^2x$ and, since there is only one generator, we have $I(\overline Y)=(wy^2-x^3+w^2x)$. My two questions:

1) Is it okay to visualize this primarily in the affine chart $w\neq 0$ ($\mathbb A^2$) and view the finite points on the curve as the "same thing" as the regular curve?

2) For the infinite points, if $w=0$ we find $x=0$, yielding one distinguished point $(w,x,y)=(0,0,1)$ on the line at infinity. Why, geometrically, is only one point at infinity needed to projectively close this curve as opposed to two? More generally, how should we think of the line (hyperplane) at infinity in $\mathbb P^2$?

Comment: Maybe it's good to start with conics (there are basically only two).

Comment: 1) It really depends on what you mean by "okay"! Sometimes one gets into hot water ignoring points off of an affine patch. 2) There is only one point because the tangent line is inflectionary there, that is, $w=0$ already meets the curve in multiplicity 3.

Comment: Have you thought about the relation between your complex cubic plane curve (and its usual real picture, 1 in http://tinyurl.com/zsnza6c) and a torus? If you slice the torus in such a way as to obtain two circles, this is the real projective picture. Deleting a point from one of the circles and allowing the two "loose ends" that remain to fly off to infinity, you get the real affine picture. Having this whole process in my head has proved helpful.